# Azure Data Factory: Copy activity executionDetails reporting 0 seconds by total reach more than 20 seconds

Tags: azure-data-factory

We've a Copy Activity copying files from On-Prem to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. Most of the times, the activity takes less than 10 seconds but around 0.2% of the activities take much more times. It sounds a bit random and this is not linked to the size of the file.

When drilling down on the execution details

```
ADFActivityRun
| where TimeGenerated > datetime('2023-08-01') 
| where TimeGenerated < datetime('2023-08-18')
| where ActivityName == "Copy files from Radar to DataLake"
| where Status in ('Succeeded')
| extend O = parse_json(Output)
| where O.copyDuration > 20
| project O.filesWritten, O.copyDuration
    , TransferDuration = O.executionDetails[0].profile.transfer.duration
    , ListingSource = O.executionDetails[0].profile.transfer.details.listingSource.workingDuration
    , ReadingFromSource = O.executionDetails[0].profile.transfer.details.readingFromSource.workingDuration
    , WritingToSink = O.executionDetails[0].profile.transfer.details.writingToSink.workingDuration
| limit 1000
```

We've the following result:

[image: Kusto results]

Clearly there is no file written in the sink (due to a condition, that's normal) but the Total Duration is really long and not affected by the listing duration or read from source, write to sink.

Any idea about the potential issue?

Comment: Most probably something about your Self-hosted IR. Can you give me the details of your IR ? It can be something related to your on-prem data source as well (What is it?)

Comment: What kind of info do you expect on the SHIR? The on-prem data source is a file system.

Comment: if this long time is mostly taken up by time to first byte, then it suggests your file system is busy or there is network problem. I do not think the problem is on azure or sink side. Is the SHIR behind a Vnet or any kind of firewall? Whats your SHIR based on

Comment: This question has closed due to not programming related question. Please do ask your question on [Microsoft Q&A platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html).